# Question about implicit differentiation and y derivative

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation, chain-rule

Suppose I have:
$$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$
Then,
$$d/dx(x^2) + d/dx(y^2) = d/dx(1)$$
$$2x + 2y*y' = 0$$
$$y' = -2x/2y = -x/y$$

What I don't get is when we do $d/dx(y^2)$, where do I get the $y'$ from? In $d/dx(x^2)$, its simply $2x$ ... for $d/dx(y^2)$, why isn't it just $2y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that $y$ is a function of $x$, that is $y=y(x)$.

Using the chain rule you can compute 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d(y^2(x))}{dx} = 2y \frac{dy}{dx}
\end{equation}

You should read the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).