# Equality Preservation & Applying Operations to Both Sides of an Equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we add a constant to both sides of an equation, we will get a new equation with identical solutions.

This is mostly true for multiplication and square roots, but there are some minor complications/exceptions.

Taking the derivative of both sides will result in entirely different solutions.

Is there a formal way to show how performing some operation/action on both sides of an equation will affect the solutions of the resulting equation?

Comment: "*Taking the derivative of both sides...*" $\;-\;$ See [Is differentiating on both sides of an equation allowed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475013/is-differentiating-on-both-sides-of-an-equation-allowed)